# Angular 2 Output EventEmitter doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript

i have parent class like this:

```
export class BaseForm {
  @Output() public eventSubmit:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  public emitForm() :void {
   const params = this.getParams();
   this.eventSubmit.emit(params);
  }

  public onSubmit(){
  if (!this.isValid) {
   return;
  }
  this.emitForm()
 }
}
```

And child:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-auth-form',
  templateUrl: './auth-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./auth-form.component.styl'],

})
export class AuthFormComponent extends BaseForm { }
```

then i try to bind in another component like this:

```
<app-auth-form
  (eventSubmit)="tap($event)"
  [error]="error">
</app-auth-form>
```

tap is just display emited data. So, then i emit something in BaseForm i have nothing in logs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Update:

By the end of November 2016 Angular's team has introduced decorators inheritance. 
Here are the rules to keep in mind when you want to use it:

> - class decorators are inherited, but never merged from parent into child class
> - ctor parameters and decorators are inherited if child class does not define an own ctor
> - we inherit decorators that are defined on a parent method / property into the - child class if the child class does not redefine this
>     method / property
> - we inherit lifecycle methods

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11606#issuecomment-261625522

### Original answer:

Method / property decorators like `@Input()`, `@Output()`and class decorators like `@Component()`, `@Directive()` etc are **not** inherited. You have to add

```
@Output() public eventSubmit:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

also to your child class to make it work.

**Edit:** here is an example of extending component I've made some time ago (popover extends tooltip) http://plnkr.co/edit/n5jCg3sK6VRu7fZfj7i2?p=preview

Comment: Ding ding, metadata decorators are not inheritable.

Comment: thanks, it's very sad, any alternatives or only add to child class?

Comment: @Unfeeling, decorators inheretance has been introduced, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add that directly as @Input or as like @Component, doesn't work like that, you have to include the @Output as reference for the emitter, since doesn't inherited.

Answer (score -1):

If you add a decorator to a child for example @Input and the parent already has an @Output emit event then the child will not respond to that out event. In this case you'll need to remove from child and add the @Input to the parent or in addition to the @Input in the child you also add the @Output to the child just like it is in the parent.

```
---Child will not respond to emitter inheritted from parent - THIS WILL NOT WORK
-Parent
    .
    .
    @Output emitter = new EventEmitter();
    .
    .

-Child extends Parent
    .
    .
    @Input foo = blah;
    .
    .

---Solution 1.

-Child extend Parent and include a declaration for @Output
    .
    .
    @Input foo = blah;
    @Output emitter = new EventEmitter(); //this will also be in the Parent
    .
    .

---Solution 2.
-Child - Remove the @Input from child and add it to the parent
    .
    .
    
    .
    .

-Parent
    .
    .
    @Input foo = blah; //This is no longer in the child only in the parent
    @Output emitter = new EventEmitter();
    .
    .
```

Both Soln. 1 and 2 will work.